# How to track changes to Objects in Eclipse/Git?

Tags: standard-objects, git

I modified a Link(Javascript) on the Account Object directly in my org.

I want to get this change in my eclipse, so that I push this to my Git branch.

When I right click inside the file in eclipse(force IDE) and select refresh from server,it does nothing.

I even tried Synchronize with server and same result.

How do you guys in these kind of situations?? Directly edit the objects in eclipse or in your respective org..

I am little confused here on what is the flow to follow here in a team so that I can send my changes to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IDE has a lot of issues, and correctly refreshing them is one of them.

Right click your project -> Add/Remove Metadata components.

Click on Add/Remove.  Once the list comes up, hit the Refresh button in the top right corner.  After that hit 'Ok' then 'Apply' then 'Ok'.  It should update it.

Comment: @ram Great!  If it works you should mark it as your answer.